# Need help using Rabbit annotations to consume data in Spring Boot with AMQP

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations, rabbitmq

I'm new to Spring and RabbitMQ and have figured out how to consume messages using something like this:

CONFIGURATION FILE:

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ConsumerConfiguration {

    private String queueName;

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    public void setQueueName(final String queueName) {
        this.queueName = queueName;
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(this.connectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter messageConverter() {
        final Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer() {
        final SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(this.connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(this.queueName);
        container.setMessageListener(messageListenerAdapter());

        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter() {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(this, messageConverter());
    }

}
```

CONSUMER FILE:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.vts.cped.basic.TopicNames;
import com.vts.cped.correlator.data.CorrelatedData;
import com.vts.cped.main.config.BaseReceiver;

@Component
public class Consumer {

    public void handleMessage(final SomeData data) {
        System.out.println("Consumer received SomeData with data " + data.getData());
    }
}
```

I'm trying to accomplish the same thing with RabbitMQ annotations in hopes that it will make the code cleaner.  I've attempted to do this with the following, but I cannot get it to work:

```
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Receiver {

    @RabbitListener(queues = "tut.hello")
    public void process(final SomeData in) {
    System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + in + "'");
    }

}
```

I had originally tried something like this, but it also didn't work:

```
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitHandler;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@RabbitListener(queues = "tut.hello")
@Service
public class Receiver {

    @RabbitHandler
    public void process(final SomeData in) {
    System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + in + "'");
    }

}
```

If you have the secret sauce, please send me some!  Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: I would assume that in your configuration `queueName` would always be null when creating beans..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix, I was missing this:

```
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    final RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(this.connectionFactory);
    template.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
    return template;
}
```

Overall, this is my configuration file:

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.EnableRabbit;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@EnableRabbit
@Configuration
public class CommonConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(this.connectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter messageConverter() {
        final Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
        final SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(this.connectionFactory);
        factory.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(3);
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(10);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        final RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(this.connectionFactory);
        template.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue helloQueue() {
        return new Queue("tut.hello");
    }

    @Bean
    public Sender sender() {
        return new Sender();
    }

    @Bean
    public Receiver receiver() {
        return new Receiver();
    }
}
```

Comment: I found out that I need to do the following:  (1) read the AMQP spec and better understand it (2) fully read the Spring AMQP documentation and (3) look through the material at http://www.rabbitmq.com/how.html.   I thought I could just do some tutorials and understand it.

Comment: RabbitAnnotationDrivenConfiguration should create lot of these beans automagically?

Answer (score 1):

There is a statement in the documentation:

> To enable support for @RabbitListener annotations add @EnableRabbit to
>   one of your @Configuration classes.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#async-annotation-driven-enable

You may also still need a `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` bean to register the `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter`.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#async-annotation-conversion

Comment: Also, the examples I'm following are posted here https://github.com/kop-still/java-test/tree/master/spring-boot-sample-amqp and here and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples/tree/master/rabbitmq-tutorials (if that helps).